# PHP remove image based on partial tag

Tags: php, regex

I'm importing a lot of articles which contain missing images. I can match the first part of the image `<img src="/display/modules/media/cropimage.php` then after that it obviously differs per image.

Can I search for this entry and remove the entire image to the closing /> tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to perform a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) search and replace:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img src=\"/display/modules/media/cropimage.php[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using any regex-based solutions at all if possible. There are many ways to [parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php) that are more robust.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744904/replace-images-with-regular-expressions/6745031#6745031) for an example close to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is what you need:

```
$find = '/<img.*?>/i';
$replace = '';
$html = "<img src="/display/modules/media/cropimage.php alt='whatever' width='500' height='500'";
$output = preg_replace ($find, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: Your expression: `/<img.*?>/i` is nice and simple and will work for most cases. +1 But if you want to handle those rare cases where the IMG tag has a `>` char inside a quoted attribute value (which is perfectly valid in HTML), I would recommend using this one instead: `/<img(?:[^'">]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*>/i`